# how to evaluate variable expression in spring security hasRole()

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

Seeking help in spring secuity with thyemeleaf. I want to pass specific role as a paramter in spring security hasRole() function.

```
 <li sec:authorize="hasRole(__${someVariable}__)" th:if="${#authentication}">
```

i just want to pass my role as a variable "somevariable" would have value of like 'admin', 'systemadmin' etc

FYI.. I am using Thymeleaf + Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the same basic problem in a way that avoids trying to hack the double-underscore (e.g. `__${someVariable}__`) syntax.

```
<th:block th:with="secAuth=${yourNormalModelAccessHere}">
  <li class="nav-item" sec:authorize="${#authorization.expression(#vars.secAuth)}">
</th:block>
```

Hope this helps someone.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I can get it solved by using:

```
${#authorization.expression('hasRole(__${someVariable}__)')}
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by pass some variable? If you have implemented spring security correctly, hasRole can be evaluated using `sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')` .. etc. Also, you do not need to include `th:if` since sec:authorize attribute renders its content when the attribute expression is evaluated to true

See reference [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html)

Comment: Anyone who downvoted, should explain the reason for that?

Comment: In case you're still wondering, I think the idea is that the role being checked for is the value of a variable, say if the users can dynamically configure access to something.

Comment: Why are you trying to explain the question? 'ROLE_ADMIN' is the variable here.

Answer (score -1):

I would ditch `sec:authorize` and instead write it like this:

```xml
<li th:if="${#request.isUserInRole(someVariable)}">
```

(Assuming somewhat recent version of Servlet API and use of Spring Expression Language in Thymeleaf template.)

Comment: Why would you ditch sec:authorize ?

Comment: @SAP Because it is not necessary to use Security integration module (another dependency) for something as simple as checking role.

Comment: The original question already mentioned he has already added sec:authorize which means thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity module already being used. However, it is up to the developer to decide which way he wants to go.